# Button action not call in pickerview delegate method viewForRow in iOS7?

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, uipickerview

In my app I have added custom view on picker which has a lable and button with a target method but when I tap on button method not call.
Here is my code-

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
   UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,35)];
   UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,1,280,33)];
   [lbl setText:[arrPicker objectAtIndex:row]];
   [lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
   [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
   [customView addSubview:lbl];
   UIButton *btnPicker = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [btnPicker setFrame:CGRectMake(285,3,29,29)];
   [btnPicker setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_radio_uncheked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [customView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   [btnPicker setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   [btnPicker setTag:row];
   [btnPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCheckPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [customView addSubview:btnPicker];
   return customView;
}

- (void)btnCheckPicker:(UIButton *)btn{
   NSLog(@"PickerButtonAction");
}
```